# Multiple keywords return multiple seperate index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, matrix, processing-efficiency

I have a very large matrix (70k x 700k) with numeric values,  is the column name for the matrix.

I want to be able to calculate the row average fo each keyword.

For example, below will calculate only for keyword 'Heart'.

```
names = ["heart", "braininjured", "heartarmleg"]
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], 
          [4, 5, 6], 
          [7, 8, 9]]

indices = [idx for idx, string in enumerate(names) if ('Heart'.lower()) in string.lower()]
print(indices)

avgs_list = []
for row in range(len(matrix)):
   row_sum  = 0
   avg = 0
   row_sum = sum([matrix[row][col] for col in indices])         
   avg = row_sum /len(indices)
   avgs_list.append(avg)
print(row_sum )
print(avgs_list)
```

Result with keyword: 'Heart' is [2.0, 5.0, 8.0]

End result desired is [[[2.0, 5.0, 8.0], [brainAvgRow1, brainAvgRow2, brainAvgRow3], [armAvgRow1, armAvgRow2, armAvgRow3]]

Now, to do with multiple keywords, both the indices and the current matrix looping will have another added loop,

ie.

```
keywords = ["Heart", "Brain", "Arm"]
key_idx_lists = []
for keyword in keywords: 
   indices = [idx for idx, string in enumerate(names) if (keyword.lower()) in string.lower()]
   key_idx_lists.append(indices)
```

The concern is:

1. Looping the names array for each keyword
2. Looping through the matrix to get the average sum for each keyword (after we gotten the indexes of matching cols). Runtime becomes quite long.

I was thinking of some way to avoid looping the matrix again and again.  ie. That for every element in the matrix, it would check if it appeared in the key_idx_list and keep a running sum (to eventually do an average)?

I wasn't able to draw it out, though, so I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. I have tried searching on StackOverflow but might not have gotten the right search terms as it usually comes up with "multiple substrings return a single index array," which isn't quite what I want.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Update: Edited with Swifty's suggestions

Comment: Replace  for col in range(len(matrix[0])):  if col in indices:  sum += matrix[row][col] with row_sum = sum([matrix[row][col] for col in indices]) ; and avoid naming a variable (sum here) with a Python keyword, for it will overwrite that keyword!

Comment: Hmmm do you want a global average for all keywords, or the average for each keyword ? Actually the way you calculate the average is not clear either; could you add some examples (the calculation and result you expect for the keyword "Heart", and for the whole keywords list)

Comment: End result desired is a matrix of row averages: [[[heartAvgRow1, heartAvgRow2, heartAvgRow3], [brainAvgRow1, brainAvgRow2, brainAvgRow3], [armAvgRow1,armAvgRow2,armAvgRow3]]. I can get the code running but two 'issues' are 1. There are a lot of rows and cols (70k x 700k) & 2. There are a decent amount of keywords (~130). I was seeing if there was a more efficient way to improve the code. Let me know if that's still not clear.

Comment: Ok this is actually what I inferred from running your "Heart" example. I've written some code, with heavy use of dictionaries for readability and easy access to values; tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code:

```
names = ["heart", "braininjured", "heartarmleg"]
names_dict = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(names)}

print(names_dict) # for testing

matrix = [[1, 2, 3], 
          [4, 5, 6], 
          [7, 8, 9]]

keywords = ["Heart", "Brain", "Arm"]

indices = { kw:{names_dict[name] for name in names_dict  if kw.lower() in name} for kw in keywords}

print(indices)  # for testing

averages = {kw:[] for kw in keywords}

for row in range(len(matrix)):
   for kw in keywords:
      averages[kw].append(sum(matrix[row][col] for col in indices[kw])/len(indices[kw])) 

         
print(averages)
```

Comment: Thank you! A quick question how's the run time comparison on this one? Correct me if I'm wrong, but my code has a runtime of about O(kn^2), where k is the number of times for matrix traversing?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've been quite busy. As far as I can tell, runtime should be O(kn), where n is the height of you matrix and k the total number of indices for all your keywords (and if I understand the context, n can be big, but k should remain moderate, so that would make O(n) runtime).

Comment: Now if the width of the matrix (and thus the length of names and names_dict) become large, it might be a good thing to tweak my "indices = " line to loop through names only once (swap the 2 for loops and adjust the rest of the line).